# dynamically assigning number after looping through list of names in dart

Tags: dart

I was practicing for loop and  lists and I was having a little problem assigning dynamic
number after looping through a list of names.
example: i have a list of names:

```
final list = ['liam','james','jerry','owen'];
```

and i was trying to achieve this  output below:

```
1.liam
2.james
3.jerry
4.owen
```

but i keep getting this:

```
1. liam
1. james
1. jerry
1. owen
2. liam
2. james
2. jerry
2. owen
3. liam
3. james
3. jerry
3. owen
4. liam
4. james
4. jerry
4. owen
```

this is my code below:

```
void main() {
  final list = ['liam','james','jerry','owen'];
  if(list.isNotEmpty){
    for(var i =1;i<=list.length;i++){
    final count =i;
        for(var name in list){
            print('$count. $name');
      }
  }
  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two loops in your code, thus making the names repeat.

You only need to use one loop, and access the names using `list[i]`:

```dart
void main() {
  final list = ['liam', 'james', 'jerry', 'owen'];
  if (list.isNotEmpty) {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      print('${i + 1}. ${list[i]}');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, it's just like that

```
void main() {
  final list = ['liam','james','jerry','owen'];
  if(list.isNotEmpty){
    for(var i = 0; i <= list.length; i++){
        print(((i+1).toString()) + '.'+ list[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks i  can now see the error i made.